# Adobe Livecycle - Creating an object

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle-designer

I want to create an object in Livecycle. Let say I want to create the object `Person` which will hold `name`, `address`, `age`, `profession`. With JavaScript for example, it would be simple.

```
function person(name, address, age, profession)
{
    this.name = name
    this.address = address
    this.age = age
    this.profession = profession
}
```

But how can I do it in Livecycle ?
Thanks !

Comment: I edited your post for clarity and added some code formatting / capitals.